# I want to get search result from SQL table

Tags: sql, asp.net

Probilem is .but in this code every data in table shows up

```
select * from book
WHERE bookid LIKE '%% OR title LIKE '%%' OR author LIKE '%%' OR publisher OR '%%';
```

Comment: Do you know how `LIKE` works?

Comment: `OR publisher OR` I doubt this even compiles. Anyway, for LIKE to find something you have to put some text between the % wildcards. Otherwise, yes, it will return everything. I suggest you read the docs, and/or make clearer in the question what you want to achieve.

Comment: Syntax error and other issues. (First one is missing end quote for first LIKE.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what Chance Finley said above but explaining The use of LIKE in SQL Here is a link explaining http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
SELECT bookid, title, author, publisher
FROM book
WHERE author = 'Thisara Bandara' OR publisher = 'Random Name' 
OR author LIKE '%hat%'
```

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after a pattern

```
LIKE '%hat%'
```

This could return something like "chats"

```
LIKE '%hat'
```

This could return something like "chat"

```
LIKE 'hat%'
```

or this could return something like hats

Also take note of the syntax, it is incorrect to get the result you want. You would need to do something like the below

```
select * from book
WHERE bookid LIKE '%something%' OR title LIKE '%soemthing%' OR author LIKE '%something%' OR publisher OR '%something%';
```

The reason it is returning everything is because there is nothing between the '%%' that basically means it could be anything because there is nothing to filter it by

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your sections mixed around. Use the SELECT to define you Fields you would like to see and the FROM for what Table it comes from.

```
SELECT bookid, title, author, publisher
FROM book
```

Use the WHERE statement to specify criteria like the below. From what I'm seeing that you wrote you don't need criteria

```
WHERE author = 'Thisara Bandara'
```